# Wigner's theorem for 2-state system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, unitarity

I am trying to see how Wigner's theorem can be proven in a 2-state system. Let,

$$
|\psi\rangle= a |0\rangle+b|1\rangle, \quad|\phi\rangle= c |0\rangle+d|1\rangle
$$

where all coefficients are complex numbers. Let $S$ be a transformation, and define accordingly,

$$
|\psi'\rangle=S|\psi\rangle,\quad |\phi'\rangle=S|\phi\rangle.
$$

On the one hand, we have,

\begin{equation}
\langle\phi|\psi\rangle = ac^*+bd^*
\end{equation}

and, on the other hand,

\begin{equation}
\langle\phi'|\psi'\rangle = ac^* \langle0| S^\dagger S|0\rangle
+bc^* \langle0| S^\dagger S|1\rangle
+ad^* \langle 1| S^\dagger S|0\rangle
+bd^* \langle 1| S^\dagger S|1\rangle
\end{equation}

We see, for example, that if $S^\dagger S=1$ then $\langle\phi|\psi\rangle=\langle\phi'|\psi'\rangle$, and the norm is preseverved. But how to prove that the only possible choices for $S$ are unitary or anti-unitary (this is what I am calling Wigner's theorem)? Maybe I can prove (?) that the transformed basis $S|0\rangle,S|1\rangle$ is also orthonormal ?

Comment: It might be helpful to include your definition of Wigner's theorem.

Comment: @SillyGoose In my simple version Wigner's theorem would state that $S$ is either unitary or anti-unitary. tks

Comment: Norm preservation would mean that the inner product is either preserved (unitarity) or complex conjugated (anti-unitarity).

Comment: Have you looked at the [standard references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem#Statement)?